# How to keep dotfiles system-agnostic?

Tags: linux, bash, osx, configuration, dot-files

Due to work I have recently started using OS X and have set it up using homebrew in order to get a similar experience as with Linux.

However, there are quite a few differences in their settings. Some only need to be in place on one system. As my dotfiles live in a git repository, I was wondering what kind of switch I could set in place, so that some configs are only read for Linux system and other for OS X.

As to dotfiles, I am referring, among other, to `.bash_profiles` or `.bash_alias`.

Comment: I did this with git branches. I have one for FreeBSD, Gentoo and Ubuntu. But this is not ideal.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens I want to avoid such a branch-based solution as it is prone to diverge.

Comment: Yeah, you can make it a little bit easier when you put the system specific stuff into special files. But as i said not ideal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script You can check for Darwin on OS X.

Comment: My approach basically boils down to `if (exists rcfile.local); source rcfile.local; endif`, translated to the appropriate rc file.  The main rc file I try to keep system agnostic, while the `.local` version has system specific settings.  If you want it all in a single repo you can have system dirs and symlink the rcfile.local to the one in the correct directory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Keep the dotfiles as portable as possible and avoid OS dependent settings or switches that require a particular version of a tool, e.g. avoid GNU syntax if you don't use GNU software on all systems.

You'll probably run into situations where it's desirable to use system specific settings. In that case use a switch statement with the individual settings:

```
case $(uname) in
  'Linux')   LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto --group-directories-first' ;;
  'FreeBSD') LS_OPTIONS='-Gh -D "%F %H:%M"' ;;
  'Darwin')  LS_OPTIONS='-h' ;;
esac
```

In case the configuration files of arbitrary applications require different options, you can check if the application provides compatibility switches or other mechanisms. For `vim`, for instance, you can check the version and patchlevel to support features older versions, or versions compiled with a different feature set, don't have. Example snippet from `.vimrc`:

```
if v:version >= 703
  if has("patch769")
    set matchpairs+=“:”
  endif
endif
```

Comment: `uname -s` is like `uname`. uname stands for Unix name.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas It just happens to be or is it guaranteed across systems and I can always drop the `-s`?

Comment: yes, `uname` alone has been the canonical way to do it for decades and is specified by POSIX. The original `uname` (in PWB Unix) didn't take any option.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the clarification, I removed the `-s` from this answer and I'll keep it in mind for my future scripts.

Comment: It's a relatively minor detail and doesn't detract from the point illustrated by your example, but are those quotes in the vimrc `set` really supposed to be U+201C and U+201D rather than U+0022?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, that's the whole point of this check. It allows jumping between matching quotation marks with `%`. Unicode support for `matchpairs` was added rather recently. This check allows me to use the same .vimrc for every vim version. U+0022 would not work (in any vim version) since it doesn't have a matching pair. Matching pairs need to be distinct characters.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only concerned with files that are actually executed, such as .bash_profiles and friends, you may be able to get away with using e.g. `uname` to differentiate based on the system the code runs on.

*For example*, completely untested and with the caveat that I don't have an OS X to try things on, if you currently have on Linux:

```
alias ll='ls -lFA'
```

and on Mac OS X:

```
alias ll='ls -lFAx'
```

(where `-x` makes OS X's `ls` do something which GNU ls does by default), then they can be combined into something like this:

```
OS="$(uname -s)"
if test "$OS" = "Darwin"; then
    alias ll='ls -lFAx'
    # ...other OS X-specific things go here...
else if test "$OS" = "Linux"; then
    alias ll='ls -lFA'
    # ...other Linux-specific things go here...
fi
# ...generic things go here...
```

The only requirement then is that `uname -s` works in mostly the same way (it should, since both systems are reasonably POSIX-y and [uname -s is required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html) (thanks [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12779/marco) for [pointing this out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83342/how-to-keep-dotfiles-system-agnostic/83345?noredirect=1#comment123602_83345))), and that the syntax for shell script branching based on a string comparison is the same. You can probably test based on other criteria as well; e.g., you could look for /etc/lsb_release, check whether /proc/sys/kernel/ostype contains "Linux", or whatever other tests you can come up with.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens It's `Darwin`, I just checked.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens Like I wrote, I don't have an OS X to try things on, so I took a wild guess to show the idea rather than spending a lot of time on one relatively insignificant detail which the OP can trivially find out.

Comment: Wikipedia to the rescue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname if someone else wants there bash for Windows or other stuff.

Comment: The uname `-o` switch is not POSIX and fails on many systems, e.g. Solaris. `-s` is mandatory on POSIX and the most compatible way. [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html)

Comment: To safe a call to an external command (`uname`) you could use the variable `$OSTYPE` instead.

Comment: `OSTYPE` is not available in a POSIX shell. It will fail for example on a default FreeBSD installation and can only be used in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. It doesn't work reliably in `.profile`, `.alias`, etc. Since we're talking about compatibiliy here, I'd advice to go the safe way, instead of relying on particular shell's features, which are not guaranteed to be available on every system.